# Most eficent way of .NET IPC on Windows Mobile

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, ipc

I'm going to split a program into two parts, because I'm running out of process memory. One part is taking a picture and storing it on the file system (GUI) and the other part is analyzing the picture (OCR) and reporting the results back to the main part.

The communication between the two processes will look like this:

1. Is the OCR process responding?
2. If not, start OCR process.
3. Tell the OCR process that there is a new picture.
4. Wait until the OCR process returns the result (most likely less than 1 KB of characters)

The three most important things, in order of priority for me are:

1. High performance
2. High stability
3. Low complexity - I've only got around three days to finish and test the program.

The GUI is written in .NET/C#, so the solution must be compatible with that. Which method of IPC would you recommend me to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably use [point to point queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446556.aspx) for this.  They perform very well and are stable - the kernel uses them for it's own notification system.  The MSDN article already has the managed classes built for using them, so complexity is also low.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [WCF for Windows Mobile](http://wcfguidanceformobile.codeplex.com/). Microsoft have released guidelines and sample projects for how to do this. If you set it up to use message queue end points (I'm not sure if named pipes are available), then performance should be very good. Apart from that, WCF is a very easy technology to get started with. Good luck!